# Cannot register user on XMPP server

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, tigase

I just started playing with XMPP and i'm at the point where i want to register a new user account. I'm using tigase and xmpp.js. All works fine but when i try to register a user, i get a success response but no user is registered.

This is my code.

```
const xmpp = client({
  service: "ws://localhost:5290",
  domain: "8662d6b4746d",
});

xmpp.reconnect.stop()
xmpp.timeout = 5000

xmpp.on("online", async (address) => {
  console.log("Online!");
  await xmpp.iqCaller.request(
    xml('iq', {type: 'get', to: '8662d6b4746d'},
      xml('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:register'})
    )
  );
  await xmpp.iqCaller.set(
    xml("query", {xmlns: "jabber:iq:register"},
      xml("username", {}, "username"),
      xml("password", {}, "password"),
      xml("email", {}, "email@email.com")
    ),
    '8662d6b4746d'
  )
});
xmpp.on("status", (status) => {
  console.debug(status);
});
xmpp.on("stanza", async (stanza) => {
  console.log(stanza.toString())
});
xmpp.start().catch(console.error);
```

This is the response i get from the first iq

```
<iq from="8662d6b4746d" id="e7t9y4ll60" to="ed0e2dd2-4701-4631-8d16-dfb16b29babf@8662d6b4746d/36525451-tigase-81"
    type="result" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
  <instructions>Please provide the following information to sign up for an account

    Please also provide your e-mail address (must be valid!) to which we will send confirmation link.
  </instructions>
  <x type="form" xmlns="jabber:x:data">
    <title>Account Registration</title>
    <instructions>Please provide the following information to sign up for an account

      Please also provide your e-mail address (must be valid!) to which we will send confirmation link.
    </instructions>
    <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
      <value>jabber:iq:register</value>
    </field>
    <field var="username" label="Username" type="text-single">
      <required/>
      <value></value>
    </field>
    <field var="password" label="Password" type="text-private">
      <required/>
      <value></value>
    </field>
    <field var="email" label="Email (MUST BE VALID!)" type="text-single">
      <required/>
      <value></value>
    </field>
  </x>
</query>
</iq>
```

So i send this xml body

```
<iq type="set" id="3peq9kolof" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
  <username>user</username>
  <password>pass</password>
  <email>email@email.com</email>
</query>
</iq>
```

And this is the last response

```
<iq from="8662d6b4746d" id="qmfce9m3s4" to="ed0e2dd2-4701-4631-8d16-dfb16b29babf@8662d6b4746d/36525451-tigase-81" type="result" xmlns="jabber:client"/>
```

From what the documentation says, this is how it works and the response is correct but no user is saved in the database. (i'm using an external mysql database with tigase)

The server supports registration from what i see in the features.

```
<stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
<sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/>
<register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/>
<csi xmlns="urn:xmpp:csi:0"/>
<ver xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:rosterver"/>
<sub xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:pre-approval"/>
<bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/>
<session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session">
  <optional/>
</session>
<c node="https://tigase.net/tigase-xmpp-server" ver="DVBeLFh/TPj/59OCEybudilMhLM=" hash="SHA-1"
   xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"/>
</stream:features>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm from Tigase. Have you tried checking the logs (`logs/tigase-console.log` and `logs/tigase.log.n`) in case there are any errors (you could try increasing the log level: https://docs.tigase.net/en/latest/Tigase_Administration/Using_Tigase/_using_tigase.html#debuging-tigase). In general if there were error you shouldn't have receive IQ result but rather IQ error. Could you please make sure you checked correct database and table (`tig_users` and `tig_user_credentials`)? Which Tigase version do you use?

Comment: Hi @Wojtek thank you for the response. I'm using nightly-8.3-2022-10-26. I checked carefully and i have no errors in the logs. I'm running docker on an arm64 i don't know if this can cause problems (the container start up is also incredibly slow) . now i switched to rest APIs and is working fine. I will keep investigating maybe i can put a issue on github if something new comes up

Comment: 1) slowness: nightlies are only build for x64 architecture and arm64 is emulated in this case thus the slowness; 2) if rest API works and user is created then it's not repository access issue (it's the same code) but rather in-band registration issue. You could enable debugging for `xmpp` package in Tigase and trace the logs. If you could pinpoint the problem then please do create issue on github